# Team Foundation Server: Roll back to a changeset and include my changes afterwards

Tags: vb.net, tfs

I have a problem regarding changes in a project. I will try to give a simplified example on what the situation is and what I want to achive.

Lets say I got a project from a coworker to assist him in certain changes to be made. I check out the project from the TFS, the changeset is 4711.

The project consists of many windows forms like this:

```
frm_example01.vb
frm_example02.vb
[...]
frm_example45.vb
```

I make my changes to the project, which are put into subfolders which makes them easy to identify, so I now have this structure:

```
DATA
 -> DataClass1.vb
 -> DataClass2.vb
frm_example01.vb
frm_example02.vb
[...]
frm_example45.vb
```

I checked in my changes in several stages but they are all incuded and we are now at chageset 4720. I did not touch the original forms, however I did change the project to VB Option Strict, making some typeconversions necessary in almost every file.

Now my my coworker insist that changing to strict breaks his project (though it is a bit more complicated in reality). So what I try to do now is reverting to the last changeset without any changes from me (4711), and then only apply my classes in the subfolder to it.

How can I achive reverting to the cangeset 4711 and then only apply my changes, without the changes resulting from the conversion to option strict?

As I understand it the TFS can only merge changesets following each other directly, so this can not be done, or am I wrong at this?

I have already tried to save my classes manually, reverted my working copy to 4711, and after that to create them manually again, but because files of that name are known in the tfs, I am not allowed to create the classes again by the same name.

Any ideas on this would be greatly apreciated.

Best regads.

Answer (score 0):

A changeset is a **permanent** part of the history of your version-controlled items and cannot be undone or removed.

So rollback to 4711 and include the classes can't be achieved.  [This rollback operation](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/roll-back-changesets) will be a new changeset 4721 which will rollback everything to 4711. Check in the pending changes then. You may need to solve the confics.

A stupid but useful method is deleting the hard files in tfs source control and manually add the ones you need.

Comment: How do I check in the pending classes? I cant create or reference the class or foldernames because TFS complains another changeset already has files or folders with exactly the same name.

Comment: Could you backup the old  class and folders , then delete those files in TFS first as a separate changeset. Then add the new right files in TFS again. And if  this is still not work , suggest you add a more clear screenshot to show your situation. Usually this shouldn't be a big problem. The finally solution you can got the whole project base on changest 4711 and add your changes  in your local  then delete all  coworker 's project in tfs , check in the project in TFS again. However, this method will lost the history, not recommend to use it not a last resort.

Comment: Honestly it is beyond my capacity what is happening here. I did what you described. I saved my changes, and checked out 4711. Then I manually copied my files back, and added them to the soution. VS complains about that files already being present in the tfs but adds them none the less. I fix conficts and have exactly what I want, CS4711 without option stict changes and just my additional classes, but when i check that back in, all classes are back to the mixed state. I can not explain, what has happend to the project, I am sorry.